# How to achieve a high sampling speed using an ADC with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, spi, adc

So, I am using the LTC 2366, 3 MSPS ADC and using the code given below, was able to achieve a sampling rate of about 380 KSPS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    FILE *f_0 = fopen("adc_test.dat", "w");
    clock_t start, end;
    double time_taken;

    if (!bcm2835_init()) {
        return 1;
    }

    bcm2835_spi_begin();
    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(32);
    bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);
    bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);
    int i;
    char buf_[0] = {0x01, (0x08|0)<<4, 0x00}; // really doesn't matter what this is
    char readBuf_0[2];
    start = clock();
    for (i=0; i<380000; i++) {
        bcm2835_spi_transfernb(buf_0, readBuf_0, 2);
        fprintf(f_0, "%d\n", (readBuf_0[0]<<6) + (readBuf_0[1]>>2));
    }
    end = clock();
    time_taken = ((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("%f", (double)(time_taken));
    printf(" seconds \n");
    bcm2835_spi_end();
    bcm2835_close();
    return 0;
}
```

This returns about 1 second every time.

When I used the exact same code with LTC 2315, I still get a sampling rate of about 380 KSPS. How come? First of all, why is the 3 MSPS ADC giving me only 380 KSPS and not something like 2 MSPS? Second, when I change the ADC to something that's about 70% faster, I get the same sampling rate, why is that? Is that the limit of the Pi? Any way of improving this to get at least 1 MSPS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a bit of the Raspberry Pi SPI and found out that the spi has some overheads. In my case, I tried pyspi, where one byte seems to take at least 15us, and 75us between two words ( see [these captures](https://github.com/kelu124/echomods/blob/master/include/experiments/auto/20180506a.md)). That's slower than what you measure, so good for you!

Increasing the SPI clock changes the length of the exchange, but not the overheads. Hence, the critical time doesn't change, as the overhead is the limiting factor. 380ksps means 2.6us by byte, that may be well close to your overhead ?

The easier way to improve the ADC speed would be to used parallel ADCs instead of serial - it has the potential to increased [overall speed to 20Msps+](https://github.com/kelu124/bomanz).